# How to get wxCurl to automatically follow redirects?

Tags: redirect, header, wxwidgets

I have a project that uses wxCurl to retrieve a file over HTTP. However, if the server sends a 301 or 302, all I get back is an empty string. I heard there was a way to get cURL to follow the location: headers sent by the server. How is this done?

Also, how do you set the User-agent header in wxCurl?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Call mywxCurlHttpObject->SetOpt(CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);

that will set the underlaying libCurl option correctly.

I don't know about the user agent -- you'd have to set that in the header in libCURL, but I don't see a way to set those with the wxCURL wrapper

Comment: Thanks for the example, but it didn't work - some deep searching in the source revealed nothing. I finally just used libCURL directly.

Answer (score 0):

When you call `wxCurlHTTP::Get()` wxCurl overrites all settings you've done so far in `wxCurlBase::SetCurlHandleToDefaults()`...

In `wxCurlHTTP::Get()` your can add the line `SetOpt(CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);` after the method is calling `SetCurlHandleToDefaults()` or you just inherit the method in a new class and add it there.

I've tried it with my RSS import tool written in wxWidgets & wxCurl. It worked!

Comment: To change the User-agent add:
SetOpt(CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.0)"); or whatever you want to set...